# Obtaining a list of cities from geocode without a map - Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

My mobile App needs to give the user the possibility to select a city in a cities list.

Google geocode has proven very good. For example, I can use the french "Londres" for London or the Italian "Parigi" for Paris.

But the usage limits (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=fr#Limits) say that I cannot use it without a map. Using a map on this part of my app would be confusing and slow too. I use google maps in other parts of my app.

I know there is another Google API to get the list of locations and all one needs to display is a Google logo but I cannot remember which API it is.

Is there a way to bypass this restriction

Comment: the places-API may be used without a map when you display the logo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the Places Autocomplete API. I believe you can use it without a map provided you include the Google logo (which is included by default).

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete

Comment: Yes !!! https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=fr#LogoRequirements